# How to create sortable array (draggable) in configuration

Tags: magento2, configuration, programmatically

I would like to create an array in a custom module configuration where I can manually order the lines thanks to drag & drop.

I can see there is a similar behavior in the related products when editing a product.

The array lines would contain 4 columns:
draggable handle, title, checkbox or dropdown and text input.

How should I proceed?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: have you try anything from code side?

Comment: @Rakesh See details in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it in an easier way.
I thought I had to use a grid like the related products (product edition in the catalog).

The solution I used maybe is not the better one, but simple:

- Create a field in system.xml with Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized as backend_model. This allow me to benefit from automatic behavior to save the configuration for example.
- In the frontend_model, I add my columns to be compliant with the model (function _prepareToRender). I add a custom function to build my data.
- In the phtml file I build my array and add a JS script to use JQuery-ui Sortable. This script is similar but simpler to the Magento one (bindSortable) that can be found in /lib/web/mage/adminhtml/grid.js

Comment: Could you share your answer?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to do it using Provided Magento's sort widget.

1. Add a block on admin config pages.
2. The block would add JS code on the page.
3. JS code will simply make the necessary tbody sortable as soon as user lands on the configuration page.

Code example:

https://github.com/wizzy-ai/wizzy-search-magento-2/commit/2ee094fbd66f1a6ac183663abff6fb2d4e219717